# S3 public read-only files but private directories

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a sub directory under a bucket with ~7000 sub directories. And then each of those sub directories may have 1-100 files.

I need the files to be public, but I don't want anyone to be able to see the list of subdirectories, or even the list of files under a given directory.

I know I can set the ACL for the files to read-only, and then i think I can set the directory to private. But for this many files, I'm hoping there is a much easier solution?

Comment: Can you explain a little more about why you want people to be able to get files but not to be able to list files? PS you cannot set a 'directory to private' - there are no directories. What you can do, however, is deny users the ability to invoke ListObjects.

Comment: Sure. I am hosting files there that my software will pull down to user's machines on demand. I don't really need the user to know about S3 since the software handles it. But I also don't want them to easy download everything.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To allow everyone to get objects, but not allow anyone to list objects, you can apply a bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AddPerm",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/myfolder1/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/myfolder2/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Note that anyone who discovers the URL of an object can retrieve that object.

Comment: So its not possible to have something like "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/**/*.txt" to say all the text files? I've tried experimenting with extensions, but I can't seem to get it to work or see any documentation.

Comment: @Dustin Unfortunately, I don't think they support wildcards like that yet.

Comment: @jarmod Can anyone upload files to the bucket? Which line is preventing this from happening.

Comment: @horse No, the policy only allows GetObject (download). It doesn’t need to deny uploads because deny is the implicit default rule.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you don't need to do anything. 
Just make your bucket public and give out links to individual files.

S3 does not actually have directories and files. It's just a key -> object mapping. The "directories" is just a convention to help people, but internally there is no structure.

2 scenarios:

- Users not going through AWS auth (hitting the public URL for the object) will not be able to see the structure. Disable Read access for the Everyone group for the bucket itself, and then enable Read access for the individual files within the bucket
- if you need to provide AWS credentials, only give the GetObject permission (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/using-with-s3-actions.html)

Comment: But if I have a file http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/myDir/Hello.txt... if the I look at http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/myDir in a browser, the entire contrents of the directory are listed. That is what I want to prevent.

Comment: disable Read access for the Everyone group for the bucket itself, and then enable Read access for the individual files within the bucket

Comment: to solve the large number of file, you could just script it to set the ACLs on the files

Comment: I have written a script in java, but I was hoping there was just a policy I could set so its always the case.

Comment: @Dustin wait... *the I look at mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/myDir in a browser* ... this does not compute.  S3 does not do directory listings.  If you go to the *root* of a bucket with the "list" permission granted to everyone, you get an XML dump of the objects... but you see listings at the directory level? That should not be possible. This needs clarification.

Comment: maybe there is an index file in there? do you have anything else that runs on top of S3 and might generate this?

Answer (score 0):

For people with this issue that are still working with an empty bucket, what worked for me was to allow public ACLs for that bucket, from the public access configuration tab, and then pass the property `{ ACL: "public-read" }` when uploading the file with the upload method of the SDK. This way new files have public links, but the bucket is still restricted. The bad part is that previous files remain without that public-read ACL. The documentation says you can assign ACLs in batches so maybe that's an option for non empty buckets too.

Comment: Worth mentioning that, as a general rule, AWS recommends using S3 bucket policies or IAM policies for access control. S3 ACLs is a legacy access control mechanism that predates IAM.